# Error error in operand of ‘->’ which has non-pointer type ‘sensor_msgs::PointCloud’

Tags: ros, sonar, laserscan, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wrote a code to convert from laserscan points to sonar scan point from the following link

wiki.ros.org/laser_geometry
where they provide the following code

```
Laser_geometry::LaserProjection projector_;
tf::TransformListener listener_;
void scanCallback (const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& scan_in)
{
    if(!listener_.waitForTransform(
    scan_in->header.frame_id,
    "/base_link",
    scan_in->header.stamp + ros::Duration().fromSec(scan_in->ranges.size()*scan_in->time_increment),
    ros::Duration(1.0))){
 return;
 }

   sensor_msgs::PointCloud cloud;
   projector_.transformLaserScanToPointCloud("/base_link",*scan_in,
         cloud,listener_);

   // Do something with cloud.
}
```

This what I added only

```
Laser_geometry::LaserProjection projector_;
tf::TransformListener listener_;
void scanCallback (const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& scan_in)
{
    if(!listener_.waitForTransform(
    scan_in->header.frame_id,
    "/base_link",
    scan_in->header.stamp + ros::Duration().fromSec(scan_in->ranges.size()*scan_in->time_increment),
    ros::Duration(1.0))){
 return;
 }

   sensor_msgs::PointCloud cloud;
   projector_.transformLaserScanToPointCloud("/base_link",*scan_in,
         cloud,listener_);

   // Do something with cloud.
    // this what I added it 

      for(int i=0; i< cloud->points.size(); ++i)
          {
             Eigen::Vector3d data(cloud->points[i].x,cloud->points[i].y,0.0);
          }

}
```

I got the following error
base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘sensor_msgs::PointCloud’

how can I solve it ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/152371/error-error-in-operand-of-%E2%80%98-%3E%E2%80%99-which-has-non-pointer-type-%E2%80%98sensor_msgs::pointcloud%E2%80%99/) by [RSA](https://answers.ros.org/users/13151/rsa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2014-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This really is a C++ question, you probably want to read up on how pointers work in C++. Your "cloud" variable is allocated on the stack and not via a pointer, so you cannot access it´s elements using the `->` operator. So everytime you access a member of cloud you have to use (for example)

```
cloud.points.size()
```

as opposed to

```
cloud->points.size()
```

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RSA](https://answers.ros.org/users/13151/rsa/) on 2014-04-12**:
thank you it worked